# Restoring RootViewController's original state

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am building an static library that provides UI stuff onto different apps and whenever I set the app delegate's window rootviewcontroller dynamically, I need to know how to restore it without losing all view controllers presented. Let's say I had this code

```
@interface SampleViewController : UIViewController{
    UIViewController *_originalRootViewController;
}
...
-(IBAction)openSomething:(id)sender{
    UIWindow * window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    _originalRootViewController = window.rootViewController;
    window.rootViewController = self;
}

-(IBAction)closeSomething:(id)sender{
    UIWindow * window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
    //PROBLEM, doing this shows the first view of the app instead of the latest view controller that was pushed on the view hierarchy
    window.rootViewController = _originalRootViewController;
}
```

Any advice on how to fix this issue? Before I asked another question regarding using 2 UIWindows but other people told me to use only 1 UIWindow despite me telling them its not possible because of this issue.

Comment: It is not impossible, but you need to understand what you are doing. What kind of view controller do you use as the original root controller and how do you expect it to restore its "view hierarchy
" of what I guess is the views of the other view controllers ?

Comment: @A-Live, the library I'm providing will be used by other users, meaning that the original root controller can be anything. In my case, My test app uses a tab controller as root. At some point after some controller gets presented modally or pushed in navigation stack that this SampleViewController get used as root controller. When closing, it should show the view controller of where the sample controller gets open instead of the tab controller, which is the root

Comment: The only way modally presented view controllers should be dismissed is by designed methods, that's the point of using such style - not different animation.

Comment: @A-Live not sure what your talking about here